# Does the most optimal way to update an entity by ensuring that it's existing is the combination of getOne() and save() in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know there are several ways that we can follow to update an existing entity. I will mention two ways below.I need to clarify if my opinion regarding these two methods is correct. The ultimate goal is to find the most optimal way that we can follow to update an entity by ensuring the primary key is valid before the updation. So feel free to state any other mechanism.

Method 1:

- First get and proxy object related to updating entity with the aid of `getOne()` method.
- Then setting the necessary fields to be updated by setters to that proxy object.
- Use save method to update the entity.
  In here I am using `getOne()` method before the save to ensure that I am updating an existence entity.Otherwise according to my knowledge if the entity's primary key is not an auto generated field any new primary key inserted to the `save()` method will create a new entity in the database.  So by following the `getOne()` method I can have an EntityNotFound exception in the end of the `save()` method call if the inserted id is not an existing one.
  So basically following this way  I can omit a database hit which will trigger generally to `find()` the given id is existing before saving the entity.According to my opinion this is the most optimal way that we can follow to update a given entity by ensuring the given id is always existing .The problem is I didn't see this method in any tutorial or website before.This was implemented by self.So I need to know if there any disadvantage that we can have by following this mechanism over the method two.

```
try {

        CustomerCategory customerCategory = customerCategoryRepository.getOne(customerCategoryRequestDto.getCode());
         
        customerCategory.setStatus(customerCategoryRequestDto.getStatus());
     
        CustomerCategory savedCustomerCategory = customerCategoryRepository.save(customerCategory);
        CustomerCategoryResponseDto customerCategoryResponseDto = modelMapper.map(savedCustomerCategory, CustomerCategoryResponseDto.class);
        return customerCategoryResponseDto;

      } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
          throw new EntityNotFoundException(ExceptionMessage.MSG_ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
      }
```

Method 2:

- First see if the given id is existing in the database.Otherwise inform the end user that the given id is not existing in the database.
- Then perform the updation. In here I am using an query to update the entity .But this can be easily achieve by setting the necessary fields to the found entity from the previous `find()` method call and by calling the `save()` method.
  But the problem here I see is we need one additional query to ensure that the given id is valid.So I think this will definitely decrease the database performance.But in most websites and tutorials most of the authors follow this mechanism.I don't see any practical use case or need that we need this mechanism over the first one.

```
 Optional<CustomerCategory> searchedCustomerCategory = customerCategoryRepository.findById(customerCategoryRequestDto.getCode());
        if (!searchedDbpCustomerCategory.isPresent()) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(ExceptionMessage.MSG_ENTITY_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        customerCategoryRepository.updateCustomerCategory(CustomerCategoryStatus.DELETED.toString(), customerCategoryRequestDto.getCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are cases and cases.

When you only need a reference (e.g. to maintain a relationship), then use `JpaRepository#getOne(ID id)`.

When you need to update the entity, use `CrudRepository#findById(ID id)`.

**But why?**

Be aware that doing this:

```
Entity ref = repo.getOne(1l);
ref.setAttribute("value");
```

has only one difference from doing this:

```
Entity entity = repo.findById(1l);
entity.setAttribute("value");
```

The difference is that the load operation is `Lazy` in `getOne` and `Eager` in `findById`.

But there's no performance gain when you need to update a column from the entity.

When you call a setter or a getter on the reference, the persistence provider DOES hit the database in order the bring the data. This is what Lazy load mean - only load WHEN YOU NEED. By calling a setter, you do need the data, then the persistence provider will perform a select on the database.

So there's no real gain on using `getOne` over `findById` when your goal is to update the entity.

Also, be aware that `getOne` [**is deprecated**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) in favor of [`getById`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getById-ID-), which does just the same.

Comment: There's no doubt in a lazy loaded instance calling the getter will hit the database to get the relevant data.But how calling setters leads to hit the database.In here I only need setters to set the data.There is no need of any getter to complete the process. Because I am not fetching anything from the database. Thanks for letting me the getOne() is deprecated , Intelij IDEA didn't gave a warning  by saying that it's deprecated.

Comment: I don't know about it's internals, but this is the way Hibernate and other providers works. I guess there's a reason for that. Maybe because `EntityManager#merge(S entity)` in Hibernate's implementation do need the current value in order to check if it has to call an update, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Are you sure in a setter call there's a database hit?

Comment: Yes, I'am. You can try it yourself by setting `spring.jpa.show-sql` to `true` in your project and test it out.

Comment: Yep it's already in my application configurations , I will check it by tomorrow. But as far as I remember log doesn't contain any database hit.I will verify it by tomorrow.

Comment: But you are sure of the fact that for this particular scenario, there will be the same amount of database hits will occur in both methods.